# Why android studio attach app by native debugger will execute gradle task

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, gradle

Attach app by Java debugger will not execute this task.
Why?Can I skip this step? This step takes about 40 seconds.
[image]

Comment: `-x assembleDebug` ?

Comment: this task such as :app:assembleDebug